# Bootstrap 4 columns without wrap - use least or most amount of space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a few rows, with 2 columns. First column is description text, and the 2nd, is an amount.

The first column shouldn't word-wrap, and as it's text, may take around 80% of the row. The 2nd column is an amount, should be right justified. But when I do the code below, each column is 50%.

```
<div className="row border">
     <div className="col border">
          <small className="text-muted">{trans.payee} - {trans.category}</small>
     <div>
     <div className="col text-righ">
          <small className="text-muted">{trans.amount.toFixed(2)}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the first column to use up as much space as possible, and then 2nd column to only use what it needs. So the 2nd column shouldn't wrap, but should use as little room as possible.

Maybe row/col isn't the right thing to use? Or can it be done?

I'm using Bootstrap 4 - which is a learning curve for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`col-auto`** on the 2nd column so it uses the least amount of space

https://www.codeply.com/go/NR35sANtRT

```
<div class="row border">
        <div class="col border text-truncate">
            <small class="text-muted">{trans.payee} - {trans.category} can be longer</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto text-right">
            <small class="text-muted">40.00</small>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can also add `text-truncate` to prevent the 1st column from wrapping if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: You have not closed second div
```

If you don't give width to div, then it will take equally,

You need to give width to one of the div, so other one can adjust by itself.

```
<div className="row border">
     <div className="col border">
          <small className="text-muted">{trans.payee} - {trans.category}
          </small>
     </div>
     <div className="col text-righ">
      <small className="text-muted">{trans.amount.toFixed(2)}</small>
     </div>
</div>
```